# Controllers not being loaded when mounting a Rails Engine

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I am currently creating a Rails engine. So far the engine has a few new routes and a few new controllers. The routes work fine, as I was able to mount them adding the following to config/routes.rb:

```
mount MyEngine::Engine => '/'
```

The problem comes with the controllers. When trying to access the actions I have defined, I get:

```
uninitialized constant MyEngine::ApplicationController
```

I am a bit surprised, as the documentation suggests that everything inside `app/` is autoloaded from the engine. I have even tried to explicitly load the controllers in `engine.rb`, to no avail:

```
module MyEngine
  class Engine < ::Rails::Engine
    isolate_namespace MyEngine

    Dir["#{config.root}/app/controllers/**/"].each do |path|
      config.eager_load_paths << path
    end
  end
end
```

I'm confused. Aren't the contents of `app/controllers/` supposed to be autoloaded by the application from the engine?

Comment: I've faced similar issue and it happens only in Macs. Opening the corresponding application controller in code editor and saving it clears the error.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like your engine's controller is trying to reference an ApplicationController inside your engine, when you might have wanted to inherit from the main application's ApplicationController (correct me if I'm wrong).

I don't know how the controller code in your engine looks like (feel free the share if I am not on the right track), but I assume it looks something like this

```rb
module MyEngine
  class MyController < ApplicationController

  end
end
```

In this scenario, it requires you to also have defined MyEngine::ApplicationController somewhere, and based on the error message, I assume this controller does not exist.

To solve this, you could either define the engine specific ApplicationController, or you can specify that you want to inherit from the root controller, like this:

```rb
module MyEngine
  class MyController < ::ApplicationController

  end
end
```

If you later want to be even more flexible in your engine, it is often left to an initializer configuration option to set which controller to inherit from ([see example from Devise](https://github.com/heartcombo/devise/blob/master/app/controllers/devise_controller.rb)).

```rb
module MyEngine
  class MyController < MyEngine.parent_controller.constantize

  end
end
```

Comment: I do have an ApplicationController that looks like this:

```
module MyEngine
  class ApplicationController < ActionController::Base
  end
end
```

Comment: Okay, I understand. What is the path to this controller? When you want classes to be autoloaded, then the folder paths must match the module and class names. So it should be located in app/my_engine/application_controller.rb. Is this the case?

Comment: Not exactly. The path is app/controllers/my_engine/application_controller.rb

Comment: Of course, my bad. This seems strange. It seems to be correct. Which file is it that generates the error message? Does it come from a controller in your engine at least? Because that would at least indicate wether it is autoloading in general that is not working, or if it is something wrong with the application controller file